# Remove Slide From BxSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, bxslider

Created the boxslider using divs and problem I am having is removing the slide completely I call

```
    $('#removeid').remove();
```

on the slides ID so theoretically it should completely remove the slide right?
it reorders the slides after doing so but the slide remains even after calling

```
$('.bxslider').reloadSlider();
```

I am at a total loss as to what is going on. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/hpn1eoh7/

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" title="Funky roots" /></li>
  <li id="removeid"><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" title="The long and winding road" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" title="Happy trees" /></li>
   <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/me_trees.jpg" title="Happy trees" /></li>
</ul>
```

REMOVE

**JQ**

```
var $slider=$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'fade',
  captions: true
});

$('#remove').click(function(){
    $('#removeid').remove();
    $slider.reloadSlider();

})
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing except it wasn't removing the slide. To test if the div was being removed I took out the slider wrapper and the div was in fact being removed. what I tried was

        $('#bxslider .removeclass').remove();

and that seemed to work fine. I had to call the child of the box id don't know why it wouldn't get rid of the slide other way though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').click(function(){

  $(this).parent().remove();
  slider1.reloadSlider();

});
```

This would work.